# Is it possible to return values through onPause?

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult, onpause

I'm experimenting in Android to see how to return values back to a Main Activity (coming from a child activity, Activity2), and I wanted to ask about appropriate methods.

In my Main Activity, I have a function which displays the request code and result code in a string for a proof of concept:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String a2return = "A2 reqcode: "+requestCode + "A2 result: "+resultCode;
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.A2result);
        textView.setText(a2return);

    }
```

In my child activity, Activity2, I have the following functions which are the only ones to call the finish() function to return to Main Activity:

```
    // "Send text back" button click
    public void onButtonClick(View view) {

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("rv1", value);
        resultIntent.putExtra("rv2",value+99);
        setResult(Activity2.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();
    }



    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        String status = "Im in PAUSE, wait a bit";
        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.a2_status);
        textView.setText(status);

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("rv1", value);
        resultIntent.putExtra("rv2",value+99);
        setResult(Activity2.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
        finish();

    }
```

Returning back to the Main Activity via 'OnButtonClick' works correctly as expected. In Main Activity, I see appropriate codes indicating that Activity2 has finished. However, onPause does not. The onPause function is called when the user presses the back button to go back to Main Activity, the standard back button indicated in the Android Manifest.

```
        <activity android:name=".Activity2" android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
                <!-- The meta-data tag is required if you support API level 15 and lower -->
                <meta-data
                    android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                    android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
```

With the way I wrote code here, it should finish the same way as OnButtonClick. Is onPause not meant to return anything when activated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override `onBackPressed()` rather than `onPause()` for this purpose:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra("rv1", value);
    resultIntent.putExtra("rv2",value+99);
    setResult(Activity2.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

And for the Up navigation button in the action bar, use something like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
        }
        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's the method I was looking for. I'm getting started with Android, and it's been interesting. This might be a dumb follow-up, but are there any "on~" methods that are quite common and should be 'considered' in all programs? Like this onBackPressed...I never thought of that scenario.

Comment: Outside of the lifecycle methods (`onCreate()`, `onStart`, etc...), there aren't any others I can think of at the Activity level. But which callbacks you use really depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. I tried out your solution, and it works, but it works for the hardware back button. What function do you use to work it for the back button shown on the action bar? Here's what I'm talking about: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity#Up